# Domestic US wire - do they get my account details

Tags: united-states, wire-transfer, identity-theft

If I send a domestic US wire from my bank to another US bank, does the person on the other end get my account number details?

I understand that the receiving bank may get my account number details. My question is - does the person, who I wire money to, also get my account number details?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know (so just a comment), but your bank account number is not particularly sensitive information.  A miscreant will have to do a lot of further work to turn a bank account number into something that allows them to steal any money.  After all, your account number is written on every cheque you write.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? are you wanting to do it anonymously? Are you worried the person you are sending the money to is untrustworthy? Are you just wanting to limit exposure of your account information?

Comment: @MartinBonner: You are correct that the information is revealed on every check, but you've drawn the wrong conclusion.  The account number *is* sensitive information (in the USA, which is relevant to this question).  See https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/news08.html

Comment: I agree - account number is sensitive. I am just trying to understand the mechanics of a wire. Would my account number be revealed to the end RECIPIENT of the wire? (no issues with the receiving bank knowing the account number). Would like to limit exposure of account info

Answer (score 1):

If they ask for it, yes.

I have received unexpected wires before and couldn't tell who they were from or what they were for. Calling up my bank though, they were happy to tell me the originating account number so I could try and figure out who had sent it.